# Lever for hot/cold water not turning to full capacity

Tags: temperature

The cartridge for my rental unit was recently changed by a plumber. However my water pressure is weaker than it was with the original 15 yo worn out one.
Also the lever to adjust the temp is stiff and does not move all the way to full capacity on the hot side. It should go all the way to the end of the red color and it’s maybe 3/4.
Also when turned on to cold the water itself barely comes on until I turn it counter clockwise closer towards warm.

Comment: So what's your actual question?  Get with your landlord  if you're not happy with it. As a renter, you can't do anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about the shower mixing valve?  if so, they have an internal bushing with teeth that can be pulled out and turned, then put right back in to allow for hotter water.  check the instructions that came with the new valve for adjusting the water temp. you'll just need the appropriate size allen wrench to take off the handle and a philips screwdriver to remove the bushing to turn it.

low pressure could be a number of issues.  If you have a pressure reducer, a couple turn to shorten the screw could add some pressure for you.  also could be solder stuck in the pipes if he didnt flush them out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Thanks for your response to this question.You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you can familiarize yourself with how this site works. As you gain reputation you'll gain privilaeges and be able to contribute even more.

Comment: However, because this is a rental, the OP may not be allowed to do her own work on it. At least not without getting permission from the land lord.